# Nginx - redirect or rewrite url

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redirect

We have nginx setup with location proxy pass and required one specific url need to redirect or rewrite when it was hit.

**Src Url:**

```
https://application-url:port/services/app1/callback/?oauth_token=<<tokens>>
```

**Dest Url:**

```
 https://application-url:port/services/app1/callback?oauth_token=<<tokens>>
```

Any solution here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems src and dest url are same. if you want to rewrite the url:

then add below lines in your server

```
location /callback {
  rewrite ^/callback(.*) https://application-url:port/services/app1/callback$?oauth_token=<<tokens>> permanent
}
```

Comment: In destination url, I want to delete '/'. You can see that change in src and dest. And also, <<tokens>> is dynamic or auto-generated value from other service not static .

Comment: ok. Have you tried above lines in server directive of nginx ?..this should fix your requirement